# How Ruby parse code, like in Cucumber gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I want create gem where I will have use case similar to Cucumber gem. I want have files with extension, like ".scenario" where with simple text will describe scenarios of user steps on site.

I need parse this and make with this lines of text something. What is common way in Ruby/RoR to do this?

Comment: I'd probably start by looking at the cucumber gem's code

Comment: I am doing this right now, of course. But good advise from someone who have experience on this - will be really good!

Comment: You can put Ruby code in a file with any extension you want. A lot of tools like Cucumber just use the [`load`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-load) method to run it.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to implement a [Domain-Specific Language (DSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). In Ruby, thanks to the flexible syntax, that's normally done as an "internal" DSL, meaning that the language itself is valid Ruby. Rails' routes file is an example of this. With an internal DSL, you don't have to write your own detailed parsing logic; you just have come up with some functions that will suit your desired syntax and then [eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) the whole file as a standard Ruby code base.

See for example: [Writing a Domain-Specific Language in Ruby](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby).

Comment: +1 just read that article it's great. Thank you for that